# SSH2 keys with passphrase won't work on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, debian, php

Followed by this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-secure-updates-and-installations-in-wordpress-on-ubuntu

I have a 64bit Debian 7 installed on my VPS(LEMP stack with php-fpm), this tutorial works well as long as I don't set passphrase to the generated ssh2 keys, with password I get error "Public and Private keys incorrect for user".

Comment: Are you sure the generated key with passphrase is inside the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on your server?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, if it wouldn't be there it wouldn't work without passphrase either, since the user has password.

Answer (score 1):

You might have better luck with https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssh-sftp-updater-support/ . The built-in Wordpress SFTP stuff uses libssh2, which doesn't work very well.

Answer (score 0):

Like the OP, I followed the instructions and double/triple checked everything after receiving the same error.

Try looking at the SSH log (/var/ssh/auth.log) to get an idea of why it's not working.  For me, it showed this error message and tipped me off to what was wrong:

```
Dec 28 06:04:23 onizuka sshd[17322]: User wp-user from 127.0.0.1 not allowed because not listed in AllowUsers
```

If you have SSH logins restricted to specific users (which I have done), you will need to add *wp-user@127.0.0.1* to the AllowUsers definition in */etc/ssh/sshd_config* and then restart the SSH daemon (or reboot server).

```
AllowUsers teranine wp-user@127.0.0.1
```

After doing this, installing themes and updates worked as expected within wordpress.